# Python Dictionary Data Issue

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently having issues with my dictionary.

I am sorting my data based on the cyear column but the RET number is remaining the same for all of the rows which is not correct. I data is correct up to the code that creates the dict and was hoping someone can tell me what is occurring here.

The code I am using for sort for my dictionary is:

```
dict ={}

for y in df2.cyear.unique():

         dict[str(y)]=df2[df2.cyear==y]
```

This is a sample of what comes out when I add the line of code in the comments:

```
        year      YM  Month     cyear
```

41523  2009  200912     12  2009CCC+  )

key=(2013CCC+), val=(
Unnamed: 0  Credit   PRC      RET        TICKER     cusip    ewretd
42371       42371   CCC+  9.15  0.026126    JCP  70816010  0.025242
47038       47038   CCC+  2.60  0.026126    RSH  75043810  0.025242

Comment: What is df2 ? what is cyear ? Consider posting a code - such that we can copy & paste and run in order to reproduce.

Comment: `dict` is not a good name for a dictionary as it shadows the [builtin `dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) function. Name the dictionary after what it contains.

Comment: `df2.cyear == y` might be being resolved to either `1` or `0` if it's used as an index. What type is `dt2`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is using `pandas` where using `df2[df2.cyear==y]` is valid will return entries where the column `cyear` equals `y`. The problem is unclear and does need clarification.

Comment: Yes, i am using pandas to return all entries where the column cyear equals y and then placing all matching data in a key within the dict. The problem is shown above with a sample of the output asked for in the comments. The values under the RET column are both 0.026126 when they should be different values. I dont understand why this only occurring for this column and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this inside your `for` loop and show a sample of the output:

```
print "key=(%s), val=(%s)" % (str(y), df2[df2.cyear == y])
```

It should clarify things a bit. I suspect the `str(y)` values are not actually the unique strings you'd expect.

Comment: I added that line of code to my question and the sample of the output is in the description of the question above

Comment: Looks like the dictionary itself is working correctly. The issue is with the values you assign to the keys.

Comment: I looked into the Key Values and found that the data download was incorrect which was causing the issue. Thank you very much for your help